# UIView not removed in iOS13, It works in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I've app initially developed in xcode 10 but I've upgrade to xcode 11 then Loader not hiding check below code

```
import UIKit

class LoadingView: UIView {

//MARK:  IndicatoreShow
class func Show() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let loadingView = LoadingView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
        if let _lastWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last {
            if !_lastWindow.subviews.contains(where: { $0 is LoadingView }) {
                _lastWindow.endEditing(true)
                _lastWindow.addSubview(loadingView)
            }
        }
        loadingView.addFadeAnimationWithFadeType(.fadeIn)
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        indicator.center = loadingView.center
        indicator.tintColor = .white
        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad {
            indicator.style = .whiteLarge
        } else {
            indicator.style = .white
        }
        indicator.startAnimating()
        loadingView.addSubview(indicator)
    }
}

//MARK:  IndicatoreHide
class func Hide() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let _lastWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last {
            for subview in _lastWindow.subviews {
                if let loadingView = subview as? LoadingView {
                    loadingView.addFadeAnimationWithFadeType(.fadeOut)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

 //MARK:  Animation Enum
  enum FadeType {
    case fadeIn
    case fadeOut
  }

extension UIView {

//MARK:  AnimationWith Fade
func addFadeAnimationWithFadeType(_ fadeType: FadeType) {

    switch fadeType {
    //MARK:  fade IN
    case .fadeIn:

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.alpha = 1.0
            })
        }
    //MARK:  Fade Out
    case .fadeOut:

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.alpha = 0.0
            }
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            if finished {
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

And I used 
    LoadingView.Show() //this is working
    LoadingView.Hide() // this is not working in iOS 13
What should I change in code because many code are not working in iOS 13 like status bar background color

Comment: This looks rather odd... You have a `LoadingView: UIView` class, and *within* that class you are creating a **new instance** of `LoadingView`? Show the code for a simple example of how you are using this view class.

Comment: I use for show .  LoadingView.Show() & for hide LoadingView.Hide()

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Your code works for me on iOS 13... the view "fades in" on `LoadingView.Show()` and then is removed on `LoadingView.Hide()`. It doesn't "fade out" though, because you have the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block in the wrong place.

Comment: Where it should be?
I used in alamofire response `LoadingView.Hide()`

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, your "fade out" block looks like this:

```
    //MARK:  Fade Out
    case .fadeOut:

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.alpha = 0.0
            }
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            if finished {
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        })
    }
```

There, the *only* line of code wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async` is `self.alpha = 0.0`. Everything else will be executed on the thread from which it was called.

Changing that case to:

```
    //MARK:  Fade Out
    case .fadeOut:

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                if finished {
                    self.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

will likely solve the issue.

Comment: Good point, I have seen that iOS 12 is sometimes (though rarely) tolerant on some non-UI thread running, but iOS 13 is much less tolerant.